# Tooltipster - jQuery tooltip plugin - link or HTML inside of the tooltip

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I need to configure tooltip to display the link once its hovered,
however i was unable to pull in any html through title attribute.

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

    <img src="img/plus-ico.png" class="tooltip" title="content that is displayed in tooltip without link" />
    <a href="link_to_other_content_or_page">Link which is preffered in tooltip</a> 
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster({

                interactive: true,
                contentAsHTML: true 
                //I tried above option contentAsHTML and and adding <a href="#"> to title attribute but i think its depreciated.

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started) , You will need to use `data-tooltip-content` attribute to point to anchor element.

You will also need to wrap some HTML element around that anchor tag and set its `display` CSS property to `none`.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .TooltipWrapper {display: none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <img src="img/plus-ico.png" class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#TooltipLink" />
    <div class="TooltipWrapper">
        <a id="TooltipLink" href="link_to_other_content_or_page">Link which is preffered in tooltip</a> 
    </div>
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
                interactive: true,
                contentAsHTML: true 
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach but, problem is I have multiple anchors with different links in one image and it for some reason grabs only one link on all anchors.

Comment: Can you share the code where you use multiple anchors with different links?

Comment: I changed id to class and used different classes for each data-tooltip-content and it works as expected, not sure if its a right approach and i'm sure there is a better and more efficient way to achieve this, but it works as needed.

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Basically you need to use classes instead of id's and keep reusing em.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css"> 


<style>
    .TooltipWrapper{display: none;}
</style>
```

```
<!-- first tooltip -->
<img src="plus-ico.png" class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content=".TooltipLink" />
<div class="TooltipWrapper">
    <a class="TooltipLink" href="#">Link which is preffered in tooltip</a> 
</div>

<!-- second tooltip -->
<img src="plus-ico.png" class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content=".TooltipLink2" />
<div class="TooltipWrapper">
    <a class="TooltipLink2" href="#">Link which is preffered in tooltip</a> 
</div>
<img src="myimage.png" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
            interactive: true,
            //contentAsHTML: true 
        });
    });
</script>
```